# Ruby Calling Join on an Array versus String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a script that creates an array , then adds items to the array depending on certain circumstances. In most cases, the array will end up with several values inside of it. Occasionally, the array will only hold one value inside of it.

After preparing this array, I usually call `.join(",")` to create a comma-separated string of all the array values:

```
tags.join(",")
```

It works fine when the array has multiple values, but when it only has one value it throws an error:

> `NoMethodError: undefined method 'join' for "Whatever the array value": String`

Any idea why this is? What is the easiest way to resolve this? Do I need to do an if statement to check if the variable is an array or string? Seems a bit silly...let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Probably because when there's one value it's not an Array, so fix that. But in any case, show your code.

Comment: I just added some code but my actual code is ridiculously long and too long to post here. It's a complex algorithm coming up with tags for a record. In any case, should i then run an IF statement to see if the item is a string or array before trying to call join? It will vary from instance to instance

Comment: Don't handle it, fix the root cause: If something upstream is returning a String in some cases and an Array in others, change it to always return an Array.

Answer (score 4):

If `obj` is your object, you can write

```
[*obj].join
```

For example

```
arr = ["Fa", "bu", "lo", "us!"]
[*arr].join #=> "Fabulous!" 

str = "Whoa!"
[*str].join #=> "Whoa!"
```

This works because

```
[*arr] #=> ["Fa", "bu", "lo", "us!"] == arr
[*str] #=> ["Whoa!"]
```

Similarly,

```
[*[1,2,3]].join #=> "123"
[*7].join       #=> "7"
```

Comment: 'zactly where I was about to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can use join on an array as following way :

```
@array = ["this","is","join","method","example"]

@array.join(" ")
```

- "this is join method example"

`@array.join("_")`

- "this_is_join_method_example"

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a single element (say, 'Hello'), you should be calling join on an array, not the string itself; for example, `['Hello'].join(",")` rather than `'Hello'.join(",")`. Of course, if there's only one element `join` doesn't actually do anything, so you *could* just use a conditional `if` to skip it... but that's kinda ugly. Most of the time, I'd use the construction `Array(tags).join(",")`. If passed a single string, that'll wrap it in an array; if passed an array, it's a noop, returning the array as-is.

Comment: Note that Dave is correct in his comment on your question, it really should be the responsibility of the code *producing* the tags value to ensure it's wrapped in an Array, not the code that later calls `join` on it.